# Balanced parenthesis

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I'm trying out balanced parenthesis problem. while I'm working on possible test cases I observed this test case.

Test case:

```
()[(){([)]}]
```

Is the solution balanced/unbalanced. I tested some online solutions which resulted unbalanced. Even though it seems to be balanced.

Comment: `([)]` is not balanced (welcome to stackoverflow, btw)

Comment: tnx bro. I read the question again, I missed this part :( . This makes this problem easier.

Comment: So how exactly can I help you? Do you need code? Or rather a _no, it is not balanced_ answer?

Comment: no is ok. btw i have completed the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no real value to our users. Asking if [) is balanced or not is not a programming question.